# Is saving a dark web page locally and reloading it in another browser a security risk?

Tags: anonymity, tor

Say I have Tor running and am browsing the dark web with the Tor browser. If I were to save a local copy of a web page and render it into another browser, like Chrome (with JS enabled), would I then have a higher risk of revealing my IP even though Tor is still running?

I do understand that you in theory never want to do this, but I am curious to know what the answer is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Likely

That depends all on what scripts the page might be running. If the page contains *malicious* code that is trying to de-anonymize you, then it is a risk.

If the page has `<script src="//example.gov/trackUser.js"></script>` this is what happens using the Tor Browser:

1. The script is downloaded via Tor, so your IP is not revealed to the tracking source, which I called `example` suffixed by `.gov` to highlight the interest in mass surveillance
2. TrackUser script, if Javascript is enabled, may or may not invoke REST methods from `example.gov` and these are routed via Tor as well

Now, remember that scripts can inject other scripts (think about Angular's lazy loading) that are not known to the HTML at rendering time, and perform REST calls.

When you open the saved page with a regular browser, you will open a local copy of `trackUser.js`

1. The script is loaded locally because it has been saved along with the page, so your IP is not revealed
2. Any AJAX call or injected script will be downloaded from `example.gov` **revealing your IP address**

This risk **must** be mitigated by proxying the regular browser via Tor. Browser can be configured to use Tor as a SOCKS proxy to continue hiding the user's IP address.

### Risk of fingerprinting

This is an additional analysis than proxying the regular browser (e.g. Chrome, Edge) via Tor SOCKS port.

One of the misconceptions about Tor is that it can protect privacy by **simply** and **only** masking the IP address, but there are more [advanced fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint#Browser_fingerprint) techniques that can be used to reveal the user's identity (or at least correlate traffic) despite the IP address is unusable. Tor Browser is [specifically designed for this](https://blog.torproject.org/browser-fingerprinting-introduction-and-challenges-ahead). Regular browsers are not: they don't try to hide metadata about the user.

I am skeptic about the full applicability of following sentence (emphasis mine)

> In the end, the approach chosen by Tor developers is simple: all Tor users should have the **exact same** fingerprint. No matter what device or operating system you are using, your browser fingerprint should be **the same** as any device running Tor Browser (more details can be found in the Tor design document).

Even if you proxy via Tor Socks, `example.gov` can still get an AJAX request containing a potentially unique fingerprint.

Reference: https://amiunique.org/

### Final line

You should not try to open dark pages you don't fully trust or didn't vet early in a non-anonymised environment.

Comment: Thanks, this confirms my suspicion. If you were to block all network traffic from the browser with the rendered page, this would no longer be an issue right?

Comment: That's why security-savy users want to use Tails, or just, well... remove the network cord!

Comment: Not "likely", but possibly. Likelihood is not established in your answer. If the locally saved page includes `src="//example.gov/trackUser.js` why won't it load the file from the remote source? Why did you use `.gov`? You say that you have a reason, but do not state it. How is fingerprinting relevent in the scenario if, as you state, everything is local?

Comment: @schroeder I tested saving this Stackexchange page and I found the Javascript files locally, so I assume that a script tag sourced to an evil source is getting saved as well. Fingerprinting can be used when IP address is still masked, but I think my sentence deserves some rewording.

Comment: You missed my point. It doesn't matter where the saved JS files end up. Once you open the page, it is going to load scripts from the remote source because that's where the code says to load it from, yes? And so what if there is fingerprinting scripts running locally. If they *local*, then the data doesn't go anywhere, yes?

Comment: I tried to rephrase, but I think now you are missing my point. If the script is declared in a `<script>` tag, then the browser will save a local copy. Now, the rest depends on the payload. I think we both agree: the script can statically inject other script tags (not saved) or basically perform XMLHttp calls. My point: AJAX requests **could** be routed via Tor if the user configures the browser, e.g. Edge, to use Tor as a proxy. This still doesn't reveal the IP address to the remote fingerprinter. But Tor Browser tries to use a unique fingerprint for all, while Edge leaks the signature